# LiveCharts2 Library, can't clear the layout

Tags: c#, wpf

i have an issue using the LiveCharts2 Library. https://livecharts.dev/

i succeeded to build the graph, and it update automatically when adding new point in the graph.
I'm using the LineSeries graph.
My graph is small so i added a button "expand", that open a new big window and there i can see the graph entirely and big.
The issue i have is, after adding some points and getting the Line on the graph and the expand window is open, when i select a new point the old line is not disappearing, and it will add new point on the graph, but in the expand window it's ok. (see picture below)

My ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableValue
{
    public List<ISeries> Series_OVL_Performance_X { get; set; } = new List<ISeries>();
    public List<ISeries> Series_OVL_Performance_Y { get; set; } = new List<ISeries>();
    public Dictionary<Int64, ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<double>>> Test_Num_AVG_List { get; set; } = new Dictionary<Int64, ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<double>>>();
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<double>> AVG_List { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<double>>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Date_Collection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<Axis> Xaxes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Axis>();
}
```

Functions for adding Xaxes and Lineseries:

```
class Graphs_Config
{
    public void Add_New_Line(List<ISeries> Series, string Name, ObservableCollection<double> Collection)
    {
        Series.Add(
                new LineSeries<double>
                {
                    Values = Collection,
                    Fill = null,
                    GeometrySize = 6,
                    DataLabelsSize = 10,
                    DataLabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Black),
                    DataLabelsPosition = LiveChartsCore.Measure.DataLabelsPosition.Top,
                    Name = Name
                });
    }

    public void Add_New_X_Axes(ObservableCollection<Axis> Xaxes, string Name, ObservableCollection<string> Collection)
    {
        Xaxes.Add(
        new Axis
        {
            Name = Name,
            Labels = Collection,
            TextSize = 9,
            NamePaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Black),
            LabelsRotation = -45,
        });
    }
}
```

MainWindow function when adding new Points:

```
private void List_date_test_performance_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.Series_OVL_Performance_X.Clear();
        vm.Series_OVL_Performance_Y.Clear();
        vm.Xaxes.Clear();
        vm.AVG_List.Clear();
        vm.Test_Num_AVG_List.Clear();
        vm.Date_Collection.Clear();
        graph_ovl_x_performance.Series = vm.Series_OVL_Performance_X;
        graph_ovl_x_performance.XAxes = vm.Xaxes;
        Graphs_Config.Add_New_X_Axes(vm.Xaxes, "Date", null);

        if (list_recipe_performance.SelectedItems.Count != 0 && list_test_run_performance.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            Table_performance_per_Date = function_general.Get_Specific_Parameter(Table_performance_per_Date, list_date_test_performance, list_box_performance);
            foreach (var Test_Num in list_test_run_performance.SelectedItems)
            {
                Graphs_Config.Add_New_Line(vm.Series_OVL_Performance_X, "X", null);

                foreach (var Date in list_date_test_performance.SelectedItems)
                {
                    var Table_performance_per_Value_temp = Table_performance_per_Date.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where (Dates => Dates.Field<DateTime>("Date") == (DateTime)Date)
                    .Where (Test => Test.Field<Int64>("TEST_NUM") == (Int64)Test_Num)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        OVL_X = (double)x["OVL_mean_X"],
                    }).ToList();

                   if (Table_performance_per_Value_temp.Count != 0)
                    {
                        DataTable data = ConvertToDataTable(Table_performance_per_Value_temp);

                        DataRow row = Table_performance_AVG.NewRow();

                        for (int i = 0; i < data.Columns.Count - 2; i++)
                        {
                            var Value_AVG = data.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(g => g)
                            .Average(r => (double)r[(data.Columns[i])]);

                            row[i] = Math.Round(Value_AVG, 2);

                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                if (vm.AVG_List.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    vm.AVG_List.Add(new ObservableCollection<double> { (Math.Round(double.Parse(Value_AVG.ToString()), 2)) });

                                    vm.Series_OVL_Performance_X[vm.Series_OVL_Performance_X.Count - 1].Values = vm.AVG_List[i];
                                    vm.Date_Collection.Add(Date.ToString());
                                    vm.Xaxes[0].Labels = vm.Date_Collection;
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    vm.Date_Collection.Add(Date.ToString());
                                    vm.AVG_List[i].Add(Math.Round(double.Parse(Value_AVG.ToString()), 2));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        row[8] = Test_Num;
                        row[9] = Date;
                        Table_performance_AVG.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }

                vm.Test_Num_AVG_List.Add(Int64.Parse(Test_Num.ToString()), vm.AVG_List);
            }

            graph_ovl_x_performance.Series = vm.Series_OVL_Performance_X;
            graph_ovl_x_performance.XAxes = vm.Xaxes;
            graph_ovl_x_performance.Title = vm.Title_OVL_Performance_X;
}
```

Function that create the Expand Window:

```
private void Btn_expand_ovl_performance_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Expand_Graph expand = new Expand_Graph(vm.AVG_List[0], null, vm.Xaxes, vm);
    expand.Show();
}
```

The Expand Window.cs

```
public Expand_Graph(ObservableCollection<double> valuesCollection, ObservableCollection<double> valuesCollection1, ObservableCollection<Axis> valuesCollection2, ViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        graph_ovl_x_performance.XAxes = valuesCollection2;
        vm.Series_OVL_Performance_X[0].Values = valuesCollection;
        graph_ovl_x_performance.Series = vm.Series_OVL_Performance_X;
    }
```

Picture of the Mainwindow with the issue:

https://i.postimg.cc/TYcwWjHZ/issue.png

The blue line is the older points, it has no labels on it, it needs to be removed.
The yellow point is the new selection.

Picture of the Expand window:

https://i.postimg.cc/wgDspLF5/issue1.png

You can see only the yellow point, that's what i need to see in the Mainwindow also.

Thank you for your help.